# How to make light not affect this object

Tags: objects, light

I would like to know how to make it so light does not affect this object (the pinkish rounded square grid in the picture), so it's one solid colour, doesn't give off shadows, and doesn't let light settle on it.

[image: square grid with round corners 3d with shadows]

So far, I've been able to remove the shadows it makes by going `material settings` -> `settings` -> and then turning `shadow mode` to none - but light still settles on the object.

I just want it to be the colour I set it to without having to make lighting objects for it. I want it to not be affected by light.

Comment: do you still need to see it as a volume (with shadows)? if not you can give it an Emission node only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plug the color directly to the material output so it won't be influenced by light like this:

[image]